# LeetCode Q1 Two Sum Single Pass Hash Table Not Working

Tags: c, hash, hashtable

I am trying to loop the nums list and find the subtraction in a hash table, if not found the number is inserted into the hash table until the solution is found. But the following code is not working, does anyone have a clue where I did wrong?

Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().

```
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize){
    
    // create hash table
    // node
    typedef struct node{
        int num;
        int index;
        struct node *next;
    } node;
    // array
    const unsigned int N = numsSize * 2;
    node *table[N];

    // result
    int *out = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
     
    // hash function
    unsigned int hash(int num){
        return num * 31337 % N;
    }

    // looping the input nums
    for (int i = 0; i < numsSize; i++){

        // calculate compliment
        int compliment = target - nums[i];

        // search for the compliment in linked list
        int compliment_bucket = hash(compliment);
        for (node *n = table[compliment_bucket]; n != NULL; n = n -> next){
            if (compliment == n -> num){
                out[0] = i;
                out[1] = n -> index;
                return out;
            }
        }

        // if compliment is not in hash table, insert it to the head
        // get the hash value of nums[i]
        int bucket = hash(nums[i]);
        node *tmp = calloc(1, sizeof(node));
        tmp -> num = nums[i];
        tmp -> index = i;
        tmp -> next = NULL;
        if (table[bucket] == NULL){
            table[bucket] = tmp;
        }
        else{
            tmp -> next = table[bucket];
            table[bucket] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? BTW, you code is really weird, structures and functions are defined inside a function.

Comment: @kiner_shah I am quite new to coding C, would you mind to demonstrate how to write my idea in C, please?

Comment: First put all the structure and function definitions outside `twoSum` function. Then see what errors do you get, update the post here with those errors (in text format by copy-paste). Also, `twoSum` seems to **not** return `int*`.

Comment: @kiner_shah The hash table and hash function is going to be dependent on the size of the input list of integers, so I cannot move them outside the main function.

Comment: Yes you can. What you have there isn't even valid C. I'm not sure about the `typedef`, but you definitely can't have functions instead of other functions in C

Comment: @HinSolo, what is `twoSum` supposed to return?

Comment: return an array of two integers @kiner_shah

Answer (score 0):

I moved the struct and functions outside. Also, please check the comments marked by `// CHANGE HERE`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// node
typedef struct node{
    int num;
    int index;
    struct node *next;
} node;

// hash function
// CHANGE HERE: pass modulo value to function as argument
unsigned int hash(int num, const unsigned int N){
    // CHANGE HERE: to avoid overflows, multiply with the long value `31337` and then compute modulo
    return (num * 31337l) % N;
}

// CHANGE HERE: added a function to free the memory (for table)
void freeMemory(node** t, const unsigned int N)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        node* p = t[i];
        while (p)
        {
            node* q = p;
            p = p->next;
            q->next = NULL;
            free(q);
        }
    }
    free(t);
}

int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize){
    
    // create hash table
    
    // array
    const unsigned int N = numsSize * 2;
    // CHANGE HERE: use calloc for dynamically allocated arrays
    node **table = calloc(N, sizeof(node*));

    // result
    int *out = calloc(2, sizeof(int));
     
    // looping the input nums
    for (int i = 0; i < numsSize; i++){

        // calculate compliment
        int compliment = target - nums[i];

        // search for the compliment in linked list
        int compliment_bucket = hash(compliment, N);
        for (node *n = table[compliment_bucket]; n != NULL; n = n -> next){
            if (compliment == n -> num){
                out[0] = i;
                out[1] = n -> index;
                // CHANGE HERE: free memory before return
                freeMemory(table, N);
                return out;
            }
        }

        // if compliment is not in hash table, insert it to the head
        // get the hash value of nums[i]
        int bucket = hash(nums[i], N);
        node *tmp = calloc(1, sizeof(node));
        tmp -> num = nums[i];
        tmp -> index = i;
        tmp -> next = NULL;
        if (table[bucket] == NULL){
            table[bucket] = tmp;
        }
        else{
            tmp -> next = table[bucket];
            table[bucket] = tmp;
        }
    }
    // CHANGE HERE: free memory before return
    freeMemory(table, N);
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    int size = 2;
    int arr[] = {2, 7, 11, 15};
    int* out = twoSum(arr, 4, 9, &size);
    printf("%d %d\n", out[0], out[1]);
}
```